# How many antennae are there on a typical small aircraft, and how are they connected to the avionics?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, avionics, radio

As far as i know there are a bunch of antennas on board of a small ([EASA CS-23](https://www.easa.europa.eu/certification-specifications/cs-23-normal-utility-aerobatic-and-commuter-aeroplanes)) plane:

- GPS is for GPS navigation in MHz
- VHFVOR is for NAV and Glideslope/Localizer
- ADF is for ADF
- DME is for DME
- VHFCOM is for COM

Questions:

1. So there are three, two or one VHF antenna?
2. How is the VHF signal split?
3. If I have two NAV instruments (KN53 and GNS430)
   how would the antennae would be cabled to them?

Comment: There is also a transponder antenna.

Comment: Also, glideslope frequencies are in the UHF band.

Answer (score 9):

The VOR/Localizer/Glide Slope antenna is usually V-shaped and points backwards on the vertical stabilizer of the plane. On some aircraft, they point forward. They look like old-fashioned wire clothes hanger wire. Newer versions can be blade shaped.  sometimes they are boomerang shaped like the old car phone antennas of the 90s.) They usually have a splitter that allows two radios to use the same antenna. e.g. [splitter](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/dmH69-1.php?clickkey=3607883)

COM Antennas are usually a white [rod](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/av529_ant.php?clickkey=9801) or [blade](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/avt4.php?clickkey=4558716). You can’t split the signal for a COM radio using a rod antenna so one antenna is required for each radio. Not sure about blade antennas.

A GPS antenna is usually somewhat teardrop or ovoid shaped. [Garmin GPS](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/pages/av/antenna_gps/garminga35waasant.php) You can’t split the GPS signal, so one antenna per device is required. Some ADSB systems have an embedded WAAS chip and need their own GPS antenna.

GPS and COM antennas can be combined.

IFR capable airplanes also have a marker beacon antenna. These can be embedded in the fuselage or [external](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/av569_ant.php?clickkey=5307).

A transponder is required in most airplanes and they have their own [antenna](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/av22.php?clickkey=619739). These are a small 2" or so stick with a ball on the end. They are mounted on the bottom of the fuselage.

Airplanes in the US at least are required to have an ELT. Old style [ELTs](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/avpages/artexg1.php?clickkey=3011696) and some of the newer ones have a piece of steel with a spring-like coil in them. Newer versions are more aerodynamic.

ADF antennas come in a wide variety of shapes. Some of the newer ones look like GPS antennas.

DME [antennas](https://www.aircraftspruce.com/search/search.php?s=DME%20ANTENNAS&x=0&y=0) usually look like a shark’s fin.

Composite aircraft often have the antenna embedded in the frame so it is not visible.

This [Cessna video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC6_vgGRHLo) describes all of the antennas on a modern C182. I don’t have most of them on my airplanes and the ones I do have look a lot different.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some images of different antennas. These are all from aluminum bodies planes. Composite planes often have the antenna embedded in the skin, except for GPS and I don’t have any images of them.

In general, VOR, ELT, and GPS antennas are on the top of the plane. Marker beacon, DME, and transponder antennas are on the bottom.

Here’s a picture of the most common arrangement. VOR antenna on the tail pointing backward. Two COM antennas. If you look closely at the bump on the right, that’s a GPS antenna. The long wire is an ADF antenna.

[image: All 1]

Here’s another aircraft with a common arrangement. In this one you can see the ELT antenna just behind the cover. ELTs are always on the top.

[image: All 2]

Here’s a good picture of an ELT antenna.

[image: ELT]
Beechcraft often have a boomerang antenna for Com/ Nav/ Loc/ GS antenna.

[image: Boomerang]

Another type of ADF and a good view of VOR and one COMM.

[image: ADF]

I don’t have a good picture of GPS antennas. The bump on the right is the antenna.

[image]

VOR blade antenna and an antenna on the stabilizer that I can’t identify.

[image: VOR Blade]

I haven’t seen many VOR antennas like this one.

[image: Odd VOR]

Answer (score 1):

ELT antennas can be blade shaped as well. I have a newer 406 MHz ELT antenna with integral GPS antenna for capturing position every 15 seconds.  Typically mounted on top of the fuselage in front of the vertical stabilizer (or fin).

http://media.chiefaircraft.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/l/elt_114-042600.jpg

Marker beacon antenna, usually mounted on the belly of the plane. Looks similar to my ELT, but for different frequency reception (70 MHz vs GPS L1 frequency up in the 1200 something MHz range)

http://media.chiefaircraft.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/C/I/CI_118.jpg

And the little stubby transponder antenna, also usually mounted on the belly

http://media.chiefaircraft.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/A/S/AS_AV22.jpg

or a blade variation

http://media.chiefaircraft.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/a/rami-av-74sm.jpg

Total count on my airplane:

GPS - top of wing

ELT/GPS - top of fuselage

Com1 - top of wing

Com2 - belly

Marker Beacon - belly

Transponder - belly

VOR for VOR/Localizer/ILS - top of tail

Seems like there should be a glide slope antenna also for the ILS. VOR antenna used for that also?